# django exclude urls using regular expression in list

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm working on `Middleware` in django version 2.1. It is `LoginMiddleWare` where i need to exclude some urls if the `requested url exits` it returns `None`

below is the portion of middleware code : middleware.py

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    exclude_urls = [r'[admin]', r'[login]', r'[register]', r'[demo]']

    if(request.path_info in exclude_urls):
        print('BELOW IS EXCLUDED URL')
        print(request.path_info)
        return None
    else:
        print('BELOW IS NOT EXCLUDED URL')
        print(request.path_info)
```

The above code must identify the url requested by user `request.path_info` and must check exits in `exclude_urls`

EXAMPLE : if requested url is `https://www.example.com/login?query=1` this must identify `login` in that particular url and must return `None`

### EDIT 1

After reviewing my code here below came with a solution

```
    url_list = [
        'admin/login',
        '/demo/login'
    ]

    requested_path = request.path_info
    print('requested path :'+requested_path)
    for i in url_list:
        r1 = re.findall(r'^'+requested_path, i)
        print(len(r1))

        if len(r1) > 0:
            return None
        else:
            if not request.session.get('user_logged', None):
                print("Session Empty")
                return redirect('login') //HERE USER IS GOING INTO CONTINUOUS REDIRECT LOOP HOW CAN I STOP INFINITE REDIRECTS
            else:
                print("Session Exits")
```

THE ABOVE CHANGES IN CODE WORKS IN SOME EXTEND `NOW THE ISSUE IS IT REDIRECTING TO https://www.example.com/demo/login` page again and again how can i stop this.

### EDIT 2

What i'm looking to achieve

`admin/login and demo/login` currently are the two urls i need to exclude while check if `session exits in middleware.py`

CASE 1 : 
          IF URL EXISTS IN LIST AND SESSION IS EMPTY AND USER HAS `REQUESTED demo/login` url the i need him to redirect to his url `demo/login` url

CASE 2 :
          IF USER REQUESTED URL IS OTHER THAN URL MENTIONED IN `list url_list`. IN  THE ELSE I'M CHECKING IF SESSION IS EMPTY THEN I'M REDIRECTING USER TO `demo/login` page[## BUT USER IS GOING INTO CONTINUOUS REDIRECT LOOP HOW CAN I STOP INFINITE REDIRECTS ##]

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: There is no regex here. Square brackets in a regex (if it was) mean "list of chars". So r'[admin]' code would match `a`, `d`, `m`, `i`, or `n` (len=1). Remove all the "regex" attempts, take substring of what url starts with and compare with simple list for inclusion (what you've done already).

Comment: @Ivan Starostin thanks for reply. I have edited my question below. pls do the needful.

Comment: `return redirect('login')` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Disallow anonymous access to all pages except `login`/`register`?

Comment: @Ivan Starostin TO MAKE QUESTION MORE CLEAR I HAVE ADDED MORE DETAILS REGARDING ACCOMPLISHMENTS. PLS TO THE NEEDFUL.

Comment: Caps does not make vague thoughts clearer.

Comment: @IvanStarostin well said :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [named urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) then you can use it like this:

```
url_list = [
    'admin:login',
    'demo:login'
]

curl = request.resolver_match.view_name
if curl in url_list:
   if request.session.get('user_logged'):
       return redirect('/already-logged-in')  # make a new url for this
else:
   if not request.session.get('user_logged'):
       return redirect('/login')
```

Comment: THERE IS SLIGHT DIFFERENCE THE ANSWER I'M LOOKING FOR A DIFFERENT SOLUTION TO MAKE QUESTION MORE CLEAR I HAVE ADDED MORE DETAILS REGARDING ACCOMPLISHMENTS. PLS TO THE NEEDFUL.

Comment: For the first case, you need to stop redirect because the user is already requested for login. That should stop your infinit loop of redirection

Comment: @PavanWebbeez see the updated answer. And don't use Caps Lock, its unreadable.

Comment: unfortunately not change in result.